# Trying to select from database and insert default value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure how to select from database and add the default value when pressing a button. What I'm trying to say is when the button is pressed it would select the table it would insert default values?

```
function budget_item($from_date, $to_date, $account) {
    $from = date2sql($from_date);
    $to = date2sql($to_date);

    $sql = "SELECT SUM(amount)
        FROM ".TB_PREF."budget
        WHERE account=".db_escape($account);
    if ($from_date != "")
        $sql .= " AND tran_date >= '$from' ";
    if ($to_date != "")
        $sql .= " AND tran_date <= '$to' ";
    $result = db_query($sql,"No budget were returned");

    $row = db_fetch_row($result);
    return $row[0];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".TB_PREF."budget(
            account) VALUES ('$date',
            ".db_escape($account).",".db_escape($amount).")";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your question more eloberately

Comment: Why you mention 'return $row[0];' statement? You row[0] return you sum value which is useful in insertion query

Comment: What if someone else inserts while you're doing the select?

Comment: what im trying to say i want the first rows to be default but seems i can't insert only select im trying to figure how to do select and insert in one function just for default values

Comment: Either exclude the default column key from the first parentheses, or include the default column value e.g. NULL) in the second. But this still leaves you with a race condition. So a better idea would be to get rid of the separate SELECT altogether, or, at the very least, bind the whole thing up in a transaction.